# How to fix ' Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings.' error in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read the content of a JSON into a dataframe, from a webservice.

I have noticed that the API generates the JSON in UTF-8 and it seems that fromJSON doesn´t recognize this encoding. Nut so far ia haven´t found a way to set this encoding when reading the JSON.

```
df = fromJSON(myApi)
```

**Error message is always displayed:**

> "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : 
>     Unrecognized content encoding type. libcurl understands deflate, gzip content encodings."

he expected output would be a DATAFRAME.